# Adding Origin to Geotiff using Python GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, ogr

Alright, so I'm getting closer to figuring this out but I'm stuck at one (that I know of) thing... how do I use GDAL to apply a known origin of a GeoTiff to another that has been processed in Photoshop?

The snippet below is what I'm trying to get working. It's a pretty rough 'sketch' of what I want to accomplish and will work it out once I get going in the right direction. I'm just hoping that you can tell what I mean by looking.

So, I take the data from a good gtiff image, and want to copy it to the same image that has been broken. Is there any way to do that?

```
def applyRefs(input, output):
print "processing %s" %input
in_file = gdal.open(input)
gt = in_file.GetGeoTransform()
if not geotransform is None:
print 'Origin = (',geotransform[0], ',',geotransform[3],')'
else:
print" this is where the function to copy world file info to processed tif `will go"`
```

https://github.com/minorsecond/GIS/blob/master/tifFix.py

Answer (score 2):

Use [affine](https://github.com/sgillies/affine) to load the world file, translate it from center to corner reference, and reorder the coefficients for GDAL.

```
import os
import affine
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()

ds = gdal.Open(input, gdal.GA_Update)
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
if not gt:
    # guess the name of the world file, if it exists
    inputwf = os.path.splitext(input)[0] + '.tfw'
    # then read and apply the world file
    with open(inputwf) as fp:
        A = affine.loadsw(fp.read())
    ds.SetGeoTransform(A.to_gdal())
```

---

There also old school methods with [libgeotiff utility programs](http://trac.osgeo.org/geotiff/#libgeotiff):

- Extract a world file: `listgeo -tfw myfile.tif`
- Copy a world file: `geotifcp -e myfile.tfw input_without_gt.tif output_with_gt.tif`